how to upgrade Firmware Version in Ubuntu 24.04 Virtual Machine
I have a server which I updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to 24.04. It is a server virtualized by VMware on a Windows Server server.
As you can see in the screenshot, I have a very old firmware version, 2012, and I don't know if it's possible to update, I suppose, to improve performance and security.


You do not update firmware in a virtual machine. A virtual machine uses virtual hardware. If you need to upgrade firmware it would be for the windows server.  If you need better hardware support you need to update the virtual machine software (ie. VMWare)

You don't.
It is not possible to update the firmware on a VM because the actual firmware is embedded in the VM hypervisor (VMware in this case) and not capable of being updated in the VM.

If you really want to know how to update it though...
To update the firmware a VM uses, you have to update and upgrade your VMware hypervisor.
If you are using a VMware ESXi / vSphere server, then you need a full license and a support contract with Broadcom nowadays to get the updates.
If you are using a VMware Workstation or Fusion server, then you need to upgrade the hardware compatibility level of the VM to your Workstation or Fusion systems' support levels.

If you are using the Commercial versions of Workstation or Fusion, you need to purchase the license for newer Workstation versions.

If you are using the non-commercial-use free versions of Workstation or Fusion you just need to upgrade your VMware.



I missed where this is explicitly under a VMware commercial contract. Fusion and Workstation are still free in many cases and other hypervisors are available and can be migrated to.

@doneal24 ACTUALLY there are rules regarding VMware even.  ESXi no longer has a free tier.  Workstation / Fusion have two tiers - commercial use and personal noncommercial use.  If OP has the paid Workstation/Fusion for commercial use they have to pay a newer license for a newer Workstation/Fusion version.  They can't just convert to 'free'.

OK. I missed the point where the OP had a commercial use license and assumed that a personal noncommercial license might have been a possibility, especially since ESXi was not mentioned. Also assumed that migrating from VMware to another hypervisor was a possibility. Assuming is usually not a good idea.

@doneal24 since they indicated it was on a Windows Server server running workstation or something for VMware, I made some assumptions.  But I've expanded in the answer now ;)
